# Is there any value to redefining objects fields or array elements instead of assigning reference to other object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For example, I have a simple implementation of Angular's data binding mechanism - notification when data on object changes:

```
// implementation
var watchers = [];

function watch(fn, cb) {
    var oldValue = fn();
    watchers.push(function() {
        var newValue = fn();
        if (newValue !== oldValue) {
            oldValue = newValue;
            cb(newValue);
        }
    })
}

function digest() {
    watchers.forEach(function(fn) {
        fn()
    });
}

// using implementation
var some = {
    prop: 3
}

watch(function() {
    return some.prop;
}, function(newValue) {
    console.log('value changed to ' + newValue);
});
```

Now I have two options of modifying some

```
// option 1
delete some.prop; // this is optional here
some.prop = 5;
digest(); // outputs "value changed to 5"

// option 2 
// instead of changing the property on the same object,
// I assign reference to the new object
some = {
    prop: 11
}
digest(); // outputs "value changed to 11"
```

My question is which of two options is better to use?
 
Usually objects contain a lot of fields, so reassing them as in option 1 is not always convenient. However, by using the second option I'm loosing reference to the original object and that potentially could lead to memory leaks if something had reference to this object. Is my thinking correct?

Comment: Why are you remove props?

Comment: Maybe I understood you wrong, but you don't lose the reference in first case, b/c you send params by value

Comment: @GeorgiiKats, sorry, I edited my question, I lose reference in the second case

Comment: What is the actual issue your are trying to solve? Or are you just seeking advice as to why you would ever replace are object in a scope with a new object?

Comment: @Enzey, yes, I have no issue to solve. I'm indeed seeking an advice as to what is the best way to update an object in terms of memory leaking safety.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you creating an implementation for core functionality already in AngularJS? You should use the built in feature. The way data gets propigated through the scopes is the other thing in Angular that makes what you are concerned with a none issue.

Comment: I don't think you're reading my question correctly. Where does it say how to implement `digest`?

Comment: It is unclear how your question is related to AngularJS then. Other than your first sentence.

Comment: @Enzey How does this question not relate to AngularJS?

Comment: It is misleading to tag the post with Angular just because the watch feature of Angular is being reimplemented outside of Angular. I assume the Angular framework itself is not being used as there is no reference to its use.

Comment: @Enzey, I used simple implementation to make case clear to those unfamiliar with Angular